# Urn contains 20 balls numbered from 1 to 10 (two balls for each number)

Tags: probability, combinations

Urn contains 20 balls numbered from 1 to 10 (two balls for each number). 4 balls are picked without replacement. What's the probability of getting 4 distinct (different numbers) balls?

What I did is: 20/20 * 18/19 * 16/18 * 14/17
But I don't know if it is right or not

Comment: Your thoughts so far?

Comment: I did 20/20 * 18/19 * 16/18 * 14/17

Comment: That is what I would do too

Comment: Really?? I don't know why but i felt it was wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

Your calculation is correct.